# UPDATE A TABLE IN A DIFFERENT SERVICE

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, h2, spring-cloud-feign

I have been trying to look for a solution, Actually I need to update employee data in a service and as soon as that employee data gets created I need to asynchronously call a different service and create an insurance table of that employee using the empId generated from the first one. I have used feign client to create a proxy of second service and called that method in the first service using proxy class, but I dont see that table getting created in the second service, Can anyone help?

Comment: How should we help if you don't post any code of this service?

Comment: Fix your ALL-CAPS.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.